# Ad loading indicator not disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I found a piece of code on codepen for lazy loading ads. The same code provides a loading indicator for ads. Normally, that indicator should disappear when an ad is loaded. Everything in the code looks fine. Can anyone tell me the issue in this code?

Note: In the given example, the ad loads only when it's in 1x1 layout. For getting a split layout, try to edit HTML, CSS OR JAVASCRIPT PART. ONCE YOU GET A SPLIT LAYOUT, ADS WILL LOAD WITHIN SECONDS BUT THAT INDICATOR WILL STILL BE VISIBLE.

HERE IS THE LINK https://codepen.io/osvaldas/pen/XNmNQN/

The issue is struck in this code:

```
{
  onLoad: function( ad )
    {
        if( ad.classList )
            ad.classList.add( 'adsense--loaded' ); // IE 10+
        else
            el.className += ' ' + 'adsense--loaded'; // IE 8-9
    }   
});
```

Comment: To properly find a potential bug in your code you should provide the full example.